# Is there a numpy implementation of hyper-dual numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to ask if there exists a `numpy` implementation of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), or any plans are currently being made about it, or if there are any well-maintained python packages that implement this algebra. I have found a few packages on `pypi` but they are either not maintained or not well written. So far, the best package that I have seen for this is a `Mathematica` package.

Comment: You can always contribute your own. It's generally better to take one of the ones on pypi and make the improvements you see it needs. Stack Overflow is not a good place to ask for software recommendations.

Comment: A different place you might ask is the numpy, or better yet, scipy, mailing lists.

Comment: This is a library-request question (which is **off-topic**)...

Comment: As for the "how to implement dual number efficiently in numpy" question, you can still maintain two separate arrays of the real and "imaginary" components and do arithmetic on them.

Comment: Apparently at least 25 people have clicked on the link I shared on the scipy mailing list :) I'm glad you were able to get the info you needed at least to some extent.